# How to feed multiple images at once in VGG16-CNN?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am struggling to implement a VGG-16 based feature extractor which accepts two inputs, i.e. the first input is the whole image, and the second input are the patch-wise images (N-local region sub-images). At first i am defining two models, global ones, which operates on the whole image, and local one, which operates on the local image regions. The idea is to add some kind of channel-wise pooling in the local model, where out of N local patches only one will be the resulting one, and after that the features from the global and the resulting local need to be concatenated.

Can you help me implement this kind of vgg-16 based feature extractor?
The idea behind this methodology is shown on the picture.
[VGG-16 fusion scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdujB.png)
The code goes like this:

```
def ChannelPool(x):
    return K.max(x, axis=0, keepdims = True) 

def ConcatLayer(x):
    tensor_1 = x[0]
    tensor2 = x[1]
    return K.concatenate([tensor_1, tensor2], axis = 1)
N_patches = 9 # local image regions
input_shape_global = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
input_shape_local = Input(shape=(N_patches, 50, 50, 3)) # i struggle with this part

Global_Model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling='avg')
Local_Model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_shape_local[0], input_shape=(50,50,3), pooling='avg')

# Change layer names to avoid confusion
for layer_l in Global_Model.layers:
    layer_l.name = layer_l.name + str("_1")

for layer_g in Local_Model.layers:
    layer_g.name = layer_g.name + str("_2")

inp1 = Global_Model.input
out1 = Global_Model.output

inp2 = Local_Model.input
out2 = Local_Model.output

image_features = Global_Model(inp1)
patch_features = Local_Model(inp2)

patch_feature = Lambda(ChannelPool, name="Channel_Pool_Layer")(patch_features)
image_features = K.reshape(image_features, (1,512))
patch_feature = K.reshape(patch_feature, (1,512))

merged = Concatenate(axis = 1)([image_features, patch_feature])

merged = Dense(total_features ,activation='softmax', name='Fc1')(merged)
merged = Dense(total_features , activation='relu', name='Fc2')(merged)

final_model = Model(inputs = [inp1,inp2], outputs = merged)
```

Can you help me solve this kind of problem, for now the issue is this:

```
**node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]**
```

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the complete traceback, not just the final line.

Comment: Thank you man, missed one more line of the error., edited it already This is my first comment on stackoverflow, sorry for the mistakes. Hope someone answer this question. Have a great day.